# spring-boot-starter-web-reactive M4 dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

There is a Class `WebClient and ClientRequest` in Spring web reactive. If we look into the documentation following is the way to user ClientRequest with WebClient.

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(new ReactorClientHttpConnector());
ClientRequest<Void> request =      ClientRequest.GET("http://example.com/resource").build();

Mono<String> result = client
 .exchange(request)
 .then(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class));
```

But unfortunately **ClientRequest.GET** method is not available with the gradle dependency I have added into my project. Below is the gradle dependency I am using:

```
    dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-web-reactive')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('io.reactivex:rxjava')
    compile('io.reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams')
    //Spring Test case dependency
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile('io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.0.1')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-dependencies-web-reactive:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
```

I could not find the dependencies for M4. Is M4 published somewhere on any repository?

Answer (score 0):

This Spring Boot starter depends on the current Spring Framework 5.0 SNAPSHOTs.
The `WebClient` API evolved recently and [the reference documentation should be up-to-date](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-client).

Your example can now be written:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://example.com/");

Mono<String> result = client
  .get("/resource")
  .exchange()
  .then(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class));
```

Comment: Thanks @Brain for your response. I was able to use WebClient but now there another issue. When there is error response from the remote service it does not provide the data send by the remote service. I am calling a microservice from my reactive rest-controller and in case of error it only passing the HttpStatus to my rest-controller. You can find the details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045267/calling-micro-service-using-webclient-sprint-5-reactor-web

Answer (score 0):

You need configure right repository. M4 i.e. milestone projects are not in the same repository as General releases. In fact Spring has separate repository for it as well for snapshot releases. Check [Spring Repositories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Artifacts)

For milestone releases, use below repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    }
}
```