# Calling Micro-service using WebClient Sprint 5 reactor web

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-webflux

I am calling a micro-service in my rest controller. It works fine when ever there is a successful response from the Micro-service but if there is some error response I fails to pass on the error response back to user. Below is the sample code.

```
 @GetMapping("/{id}/users/all")
public Mono<Employee> findAllProfiles(@PathVariable("id") UUID organisationId,
                                           @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization", required = false) String oauthJwt) {
    return webClient.get().uri(prepareUrl("{id}/users/all"), organisationId)
            .header("Authorization", oauthJwt).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange().then(response -> response.bodyToMono(Employee.class));
}
```

Now if there is any JSON response with error code then web client does not pass on the error response to the controller due to which no information is propagated to the api end user.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What's the HTTP response sent by the remote service? How is your application behaving, I assume `findAllProfiles ` is not responding with a proper `Employee`? What logs are you seeing if you add a `log("org.yourpackage.something")` operator after the `then(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain methods from the [Mono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) API. Look for "onError" to see a number of options which allow you to define the behavior when there is an error.

For example, if you wanted to return an "empty" Employee, you could do the following:

```
.exchange()
.then(response -> response.bodyToMono(Employee.class))
.onErrorReturn(new Employee());
```